# Arduino "Port" option grayed out

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

### My Arduino Kerfuffel

I just got an Arduino Nano, and I decided to first start off with a blinking LED. I did the wiring, I wrote the code, and I was ready to upload it. Verifying it was fine, but when I hit `upload`, it blurt out an error that read:

```
Serial port not selected.
```

So I looked it up, and turns out I have to go to `Tools` and select the port connected in `Port`. So I saw, but `Port` was grayed out. I looked everywhere in forums, but none of it helped.

One of the problems listed was that my Arduino was burnt out, but it still detected it as a device on Windows.

So what's happening?

More info:

- **Am I using a clone?** Yes, I'm using a Keyestudio Nano.
- **What operating system are you using?** I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to run into this problem myself.

Your board is not being detected because it is a clone. However, I looked up your clone and it uses the ch340 USB-to-serial port chip.

To solve this, you simply need to install a driver so that your computer can communicate with your board. Just follow the instructions from the following link, and your board should appear! https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all#windows-710

Best of luck and let me know if you encounter any more problems!

PS: The link also has a video tutorial if you want to avoid reading.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: I'm running into another problem. Everything works, and I selected a port, but when I upload, it stays orange and never seems to upload. The bar freezes, and nothing happens. What's happening?

Comment: Did you select the correct board? That is Tools > Board > Arduino Nano. Also just try to run the blink sketch for now so we can target the source of the error more easily

Comment: Yes, I did select it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the Arduino IDE is showing? And also, does your code compile?

Comment: My code does compile. How do I post an image?

Comment: What is the error message you get? Is it a countdown to 10 with avrdude?

Comment: It does not have an error message. It simply just freezes when it uploads.

Comment: Does anything like this come up?

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x57

Comment: What options do you have when you go to Tools > Processor? Try all of the different ones and see if that helps

Comment: Wait nevermind I fixed the problem by changing to the old bootloader. Thanks got your help, though!